# Flask : TypeError: 'str' object is not callable while validation using Flask-WTF

Tags: python, flask, wtforms, flask-wtforms

I have a very simple form and I am trying to test form validation. I am going off of the [Flask Megatutorial by Miguel Grinberg](https://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/the-flask-mega-tutorial-part-iii-web-forms). I have just run into problems.

Here's the traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1997, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1614, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
    reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/app/views.py", line 32, in login
    if form.validate_on_submit():
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask_wtf/form.py", line 101, in validate_on_submit
    return self.is_submitted() and self.validate()
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 310, in validate
    return super(Form, self).validate(extra)
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/form.py", line 152, in validate
    if not field.validate(self, extra):
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 204, in validate
    stop_validation = self._run_validation_chain(form, chain)
  File "/Users/naman/Desktop/dev/pythonstuff/flaskStuff/microblog/flask/lib/python3.6/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 224, in _run_validation_chain
    validator(form, self)
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

Here is my route function:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    form = LoginForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        flash('Login requested for OpenID="{}", remember_me={}'.format(form.openid.data, str(form.remember_me.data)))
        return redirect('/index')
    return render_template('login.html',
                           title='Sign In',
                           form=form)
```

I checked the Flask-WTF documentation and it appears that `validate_on_submit` is a function and not a string. https://flask-wtf.readthedocs.io/en/stable/quickstart.html#validating-forms

Could someone please help me out?

EDIT: Here's what the `forms.py` looks like:

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

class LoginForm(Form):
    openid = StringField('openid', validators=['DataRequired()'])
    remember_me = BooleanField('remember_me', default=False)
```

Comment: Can you show your code where the LoginForm class is defined?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/zRq786ne

I was having a hard time with multi-line code in mini markdown so I created a pastebin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please fix your `LoginForm` as follows and could you try?.

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms import StringField, BooleanField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired
from wtforms import validators

class LoginForm(Form):
    openid = StringField('openid', [validators.DataRequired()])
    remember_me = BooleanField('remember_me', default=False)
```